# jade (with express): script tag - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: node.js, syntax, express, pug

I have an app in express/nodejs, using jade as template engine.

In a template file there is this the following paragraph
`p.btn(onclick='clicked( #{entity._id} )') Click`
and after this paragraph (after some tags) there is a script tag in which there is a javascript function.

The problem is that if i click the paragraph it throws

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

in the script tag. If i see in the DOM inspector this script tag it is bad syntax highlighted but it hasn't incorrect syntax.

Furthermore if i delete `#{entity._id}` in the onclick attribute of paragraph above it doesn't throw any error.

Why?
What are the best practices to write and include script tag in jade template?

EDIT:

generated HTML for the paragraph is

`<p onclick="clicked(5025)" class="btn">Click</p>`

click handler is in external file (included by script tag) and is
  `var clicked=function(id){
    location.href='/click/'+id+'/';
};`

The error is throwed in following script tag (that is some tag after the paragraph)

`<script>flowplayer("5025","/javascripts/flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.12.swf",{
 clip:{
  autoPlay:false
 }
});
</script>`

Comment: What's the actual generated HTML for that paragraph, including the `onclick` handler?

Comment: @ebohlman i have editer the question

Comment: How come `click` is called with `id` as a parameter but never uses it? Wherre does `labId` come from?

Comment: @ebohlman Sorry it's my mistake during copy&paste. I have edited with right content (handler uses id parameter).

Comment: The kind of error message you're getting can often be caused by erroneous code that comes well before the place where the parser detects the error. Oftentimes it's something like an unclosed quote earlier on. Nothing appears wrong with the excerpts you've shown.